# How to validate the login form with 3 filelds?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am able to validate the login form with 2 fields such as username and password.But I need to add other field called customer id.this.  I need to pass this customer id next php page . there I have to store this in a variable. I am able to do all this.

But my problem is I am not able to validate after adding customer field. Because here I am passing the customer id after he enters in the text box.

When I add 2 fields I am able to validate.

**how to validate this.**

My code is,

Login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head background-color:blue>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
    <style>
       p{
         color:white;
         font-size:26px;
         font-weight: bold;
      }
      label{
         color:black;
         font-size:13px;
         font-weight: bold;

      }
     h1{
      font-weight: bold;
     }  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
   <div class="login">
      <h1><font color ="MAROON">Login to Merahkee Tech solutions</font></h1>
         <form action = "site.php" method = "post">
                  <label> Username  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label> Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <label> Custoner ID  :</label><input type = "password" name = "custid" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = "Login "/><br />
        </form> 
    </div>
  </body>
</section>
</html>
<?php
   include("Config.php");
    session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

       $sql = "select user_table.user_id,username,`password`,cust_id from user_table join customer_table on customer_table.user_id=user_table.user_id where username = '$username' and BINARY password = '$password';";
       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);   

   if (!$result) {
      printf("unable to connrct to database");
      exit();
     }  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = "";
         //header("location:http://localhost/Dashboard/TreeStructure/fr1.php");
      }

    //username field empty  
   elseif($username==null){
         $error="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=1";
         $ren = mysqli_query($db,$error);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ren);
         $to  =$row['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" ' . $to . ' ");</script>';
     }
    //password field empty
   elseif($password==null){

         $error2="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=3";
         $ren2 = mysqli_query($db,$error2);
         $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($ren2);
         $to2  =$row2['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" ' . $to2 . ' ");</script>';
     }
     //SPACE WHILE ENTERING USERNAME
 elseif(preg_match('/\s/', $username)){
         $error1="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=2";
         $ren1 = mysqli_query($db,$error1);
         $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ren1);
         $to1  =$row1['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" ' . $to1 . ' ");</script>';

     } 
     //SPACE WHILE ENTERING PASSWORD
  elseif($num!=0){

         $error3="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=5;";
         $ren3 = mysqli_query($db,$error3);
         $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($ren3);
         $to3  =$row3['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" '. $to3 .' ");</script>';
     }
  elseif($num1!=0){

         $error5="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=4;";
         $ren5 = mysqli_query($db,$error5);
         $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($ren5);
         $to5  =$row5['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" '. $to5 .' ");</script>';
     }         
  //WRONG USERNAME AND PASSWORD
 else{
         $error4="SELECT Message FROM error_message WHERE id=6;";
         $ren4 = mysqli_query($db,$error4);
         $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($ren4);
         $to4  =$row4['Message'];
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" ' . $to4 . ' ");</script>';
     }   

   //space while entering username  
 }     
 ?>
```

In site.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Merahkee Tech Solutions </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_checkbox.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<h2> Select Project</h2>
<?php 
$m=$_POST['custid'];

include("Config.php");
$cust_id ="select project_name from customer_access where customer_id=$m;";
$ren = mysqli_query($db,$cust_id );
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ren)){
echo'<form action="right.php" method="post">
<label class="heading">Select Your Project:</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value='.$m.'><label>'.$row['project_name'].'</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In right.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
// Counting number of checked checkboxes.
$checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
echo  " $checked_count <br/>";
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
}
}
else{
echo "<b>Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
}
}
?>
```

Can Anybody help me to solve this.

In login page I have tried this. But I did not get.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
       $cust_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['cust_id']);

       $sql = "select user_table.user_id,username,`password`,cust_id from user_table join customer_table on customer_table.user_id=user_table.user_id where username = '$username' and BINARY password = '$password' and cust_is="$cust_id" ;";
       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);   


if (!$result) {
      printf("unable to connrct to database");
      exit();
     }  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = "$cust_id";
         header("location:http://localhost/Dashboard/TreeStructure/fr1.php");
      }
```

I tried to print this, after login.It prints username and password but not cust_id.

Comment: here cust_id is int. Do I need to change that Id to string in the database?

Comment: You sould not use `session_start();` after outputing html code, this may cause problems.

Comment: $cust_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['cust_id']);                                  

   $sql = "select user_table.user_id,username,`password`,cust_id from user_table join customer_table on customer_table.user_id=user_table.user_id where username = '$username' and BINARY password = '$password' and cust_id='$cust_id';"; Later I need this cust_id to validate. and I need pass this cust_id to next php page there I need to save this in a php variable.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this behaviour in a minimalist exemple and edit it in the question ? it would help us to target the problem. It may also make you able to fix the problem by yourself. (post an answer if you do)

Answer (score -1):

> It prints username and password but not cust_id

You are not running the code you have shown us.

The SQL statement has at least two fatal error.

```
select user_table.user_id,username,`password`,cust_id 
from user_table 
join customer_table 
  on customer_table.user_id=user_table.user_id 
where username = '$username' 
and BINARY password = '$password' 
and cust_is="$cust_id" ;
```

You are using double quotes around $cust_id in the where clause - this should be single quotes. You are trying to match this value to an attribute named `cust_is` - don't you mean `cust_id`?

The code you have shown us will fail to match a login each time.

It also seems very strange to use a customer id as an authenticator/identifier when you already have the identifier (username) and authenticator (password) and can derive the vustomer id from the database at login.

Comment: I have used $cust_id. It is not giving. I tried to print the $cust_id. it is not printing any thing.

Comment: Cust_id is customer id, that means if user is a customer. He has some id that is connected with project with name. What I will do is , When use enter cust_id I will store that in an variable in the next php page and I will pass that to query. Based on that project name will display.

Comment: There is no `cust_id` in your form - you do have an input named `custid`. But the code you have shown us still will not give the output you described if the names matched